# Multivariable limits involving absolute values

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Define $f$ on $\mathbb R^2$ by
$$ 
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
f(x,y) = \frac{y|x|}x,& x\ne 0\\
0,& x=0.
\end{cases}
$$

Is $f$ continuous

a.) On the $x$-axis?

b.) On the $y$-axis?

c.) At $(0,0)$?

I am still in the early stages of learning this but here is my work in my best efforts. And sorry that I am not familiar with the formatting, I'll try to accept edits and learn the code asap.

Work:

On the $x$-axis $\lim\limits_{(x,0) \to (a,0)} \frac{|x|*0}{x}$ is always zero for any $a$ so it is continuous.

On the $y$-axis $\lim\limits_{(0,y) \to (0,b)} \frac{|0|*y}{0}$ I think this is indeterminate $\frac{0}{0}$, but I am unsure how to proceed since I am restricted to just testing on the $y$-axis.

At $(0,0)$ I am fairly sure that it is not continuous based on checking my work on wolfram but cannot find a non-indeterminate situation to prove it. Here is my work testing $y=-2x$. Example on the line $y=-2x$ $(x=-.5y)$

For X

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|*-2x}{x}$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{-2x^2}{x}$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (-2x)=0$

For Y

$\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{|-.5y|*y}{-.5y}$

$\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{.5y^2}{-.5y}$

$\lim\limits_{y \to 0} (-y)=0$

Comment: Where is your work?

Comment: Please format your question using MathJax.

Comment: You are using a wrong definition of $f$ for the $y$ axis! And I also suggest you look at the definition of a limit and try to understand it more, because what you wrote is not indeterminate, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks! I am just confused as to what is incorrect. According to my notes and my interpretation of the book (which I admit may not necessarily be correct), when you test along the y axis the values of x must be zero since you are restricting the test to all points on the x axis. Is that incorrect, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Was I supposed to use the case: $0, x=0$? Is that what you are referring to? I suppose that makes sense.